# Pydev error while creating new django project

Tags: python, django, eclipse, titanium, pydev

I keep getting this error every time i create a new django project using titanium (eclipse) with pydev. 
Actually, it did create the file settings.py
I wonder what make this error and how to fix it?

[image: Error]

Comment: What version of django are you using? The package structure was updated in django 1.4 so maybe pydev is not syncing up??

Comment: :-? I'm using django 1.4, perhaps it's really pydev's bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really a PyDev issue with Django 1.4. A new release (2.5.0) will be done later this week properly supporting the layout changes in Django 1.4.

You can still use the project created this way, but you have to do some manual things:

1. Move the contents inside of the folder that was created to your module (this was the structural change done in django 1.4)
2. The settings.py won't have the details you entered in the wizard (i.e.: manually edit the settings.py)
3. In the project django's properties (right click project > properties and check the django properties page), you have to put the proper settings to the settings module and manage.py.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my pydev today to the last version and now it seems to be working beautifully...