# Django app in Eclipse won't run after upgrade to django 1.4

Tags: windows, django, eclipse, pydev

After upgrading to Django 1.4, I now get the following error message:

```
raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings.py' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named py
```

I read that it might have something to do with pydev 2.4 eg: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966287/pydev-error-while-creating-new-django-project), so I upgraded pydev to the latest version, 2.5. I am using eclipse indigo.

I started to have a look at the run cnofiguration, and noticed that the django 1.3 egg was still being referenced. So I went to windows/preferences/pydev/interpreter-python, and the 1.3 egg was being referenced in the system PYTHON path.

To try and correct this, I removed the existing python interpreter, and re-added a new one. My python is run from venv, so I added this. An error comes up:

[image: Error message]

I don't think this is related, but I can see that /venv/lib has appears in the System PYTHONPATH list, whereas in Windows the folder is called /venv/Lib, so I added this as well. Still the new django egg hasn't been include, so I manually added this under the 'Libraries' window.

However, I'm still receiving the error message.

The app runs fine from the command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured this out after a few hours of trying different things.

I created a new Django project using the pydev 2.5 just to see what would happen, and I noticed that the 'django settings module' entry (see below) was *appname.settings*. Previously I had put 'settings.py'. I removed the entry entirely, which cleared up the first problem.

[image]

After this I was getting a 'module *appname* not found' error, so I tried putting an empty __init__.py file in the root of my app, which seemed to work.

Comment: I experienced a similar problem. I've put 'mysite.settings' as Django settings module and my Django app run and debugged well.

Comment: Quite frustrating that PyDev doesn't ask for this or read it from the string literal in manage.py (or at least complain if you forgot to set this!) when creating a run configuration for an imported project. But yeah, setting this field fixed it for me, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a virtualenv, this is usually the case where you forgot to add the /Lib from the base python install during the install process (so, when searching in the PYTHONPATH it's not finding things such as 'threading.py' or 'traceback.py', etc.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the following to `manage.py`:

```
import os

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = '<django_app_folder>.settings'
os.environ['SERVER_NAME'] = '<name_of_server>'
```

`<django_app_folder>` is the name of the folder containing the `settings.py` file.

`<name_of_server>` needs to be there, but I didn't find that it matters what it's set to.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. My project did not have a PyDev - Django property so the other solution here did not work. I think this is because I did not initially create it as a Django project. Instead, what worked was:

1. right click project > properties > PyDev PYTHONPATH > String substitution variables.
2. Add a variable named DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE Its value should be yourapp.settings (or edit it if it's already there)